# Symfony2 - How to install Sandbox?

Tags: php, symfony, sandbox, sonata-admin

I have a problem with Symfony 2.4
I Installed sandbox(git clone) and when I go to my site : http://sfweb.alwaysdata.net/v3a/web/
I have an error : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function bcscale()

How can I solved It ? , I tried to reinstall It but It doesn't work .
Thanks

Comment: Is BCMath installed properly? http://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.setup.php

Comment: I think It doesn't recognize this function , where can I check the setup ?

Comment: Look in the output of phpinfo() and read the documentation in the link I posted.

Comment: BCMath is supposed to be bundled with PHP since version 4.0.4... Something is wrong with your php installation...

Comment: Yes , something wrong because I can't access to /app/check.php .

Answer (score 2):

Hi mdma your suggestion worked for me. Thank you soooo much.
I'm writing a new answer 'cause I can't add comments yet.
I'm gonna add my error trace as well. So google can index it on this topic and people can find the answer for it.

I'm using PHP 7, so the command was a bit different for me.

```
apt-get install php7.0-bcmath
```

I was **clearing cache** (`php bin/console cache:clear --env=local`)using composer on a **symfony** solution and I got the following error traces:

`symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(120): AppBundle\AppBundle->boot()`

`Script php bin/console cache:clear --env=local handling the clear-local-cache event returned with error code 255`

`Attempted to call function "bcscale" from namespace "AppBundle".`

P.S: It might happen on `composer install` as well on a **symfony** application as it will invoke `php bin/console cache:clear --env=local` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you can install bcmath with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-bcmath
```